# Merge datasets using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

Below I have code which was provided to me in order to join 2 datasets.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df= pd.read_csv("student/student-por.csv")
ds= pd.read_csv("student/student-mat.csv")

print("before merge")

print(df)
print(ds)

print("After merging:")

dq = pd.merge(df,ds,by=c("school","sex","age","address","famsize","Pstatus","Medu","Fedu","Mjob","Fjob","reason","nursery","internet"))

print(dq)
```

I get this  error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/datamining/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    dq = pd.merge(df, ds,by=c ("school","sex","age","address","famsize","Pstatus","Medu","Fedu","Mjob","Fjob","reason","nursery","internet"))
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Any help would be great, I've tried messing about with it for a while. I believe the 'by=c' is the issue.

Thanks

Comment: there is a c after the by in your code which was not defined before.

Comment: @TiTo yes I'm just looking on how to define it

Comment: This c() looks like R language. Try to pass these columns in a list.

Comment: And oh, in pd.merge the parameter to pass the columns to merge is "on" and not "by".

Comment: @Vini any other way to do this? really confused

Comment: If the dataframes have the same structure, you can just append both using pd.concat([df1, df2]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi  Hope you are doing well!

The error is happening because of the `c` symbol in the arguments of the `merge` function. Also `merge` function has a different signature and it doesn't have the argument `by` but instead it should be `on`, which accepts only the list of columns  So in summary it should something similar to this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("student/student-por.csv")
ds = pd.read_csv("student/student-mat.csv")

print("Before merge.")
print(df)
print(ds)

print("After merge.")
dq = pd.merge(
    left=df,
    right=ds,
    on=[
        "school",
        "sex",
        "age",
        "address",
        "famsize",
        "Pstatus",
        "Medu",
        "Fedu",
        "Mjob",
        "Fjob",
        "reason",
        "nursery",
        "internet",
    ],
)
print(dq)
```

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: how can I remove the extra columns it produces?

Comment: you can use the method `.drop()` e.g., `dq = dq.drop(columns=["<column>"])`